# Cant call function when cancellation token placed in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have unitTask function:

```
private async UniTaskVoid PlayMusic(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //do some stuff

    await UniTask.WaitUntil(() => (100.0f - (musicAc.time / musicAc.clip.length) * 100.0f) <= 3f);
}
```

when i destroy object i call

```
cts.Cancel();
```

but when i exit playmode i get nullref to `musicAC` in `WaitUntil`

i tried:

```
await UniTask.WaitUntil(() => (100.0f - (musicAc.time / musicAc.clip.length) * 100.0f) <= 3f, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

after that i got no null error after exit playmode, but this line didnt work at all (checked with debug.log)

so, what am i doing wrong or how to cancel `WaitUntil` when i cancel `PlaySound` and make this task work?

Comment: null ref to musicAc doesn't sound related to cancellation token. can you attach a debugger and check if it has a value? also I note case mismatch in question between musicAC and musicAc between what is in the code and what you say is in exception. Could it be that when cancellation token is passed, the task is cancelled before it tries to execute. when the cancellation token is not passed then the code inside WaitUntil runs and throws a null reference because musicAC is not set?

Comment: what is cts? surely it would be the same cancellationToken?